# Regex: Replace number of digits in the the middle of a number with special charicters

Tags: c#, regex

I have a very large number (it's length may vary) as an input.

And I need a regular expression that will leave first 3 digits and last 3 digits unmodified and will replace all the digits in the between them with some character. The total length of an output should remain the same.

For example:

Input 123456789123456

Output 123xxxxxxxxx456

So far i was able to divide the input number in to 3 the groups by using

```
^(\d{3})(.*)(\d{3})
```

The second group is the one that needed to be replaced so it will be something like

```
$1 {Here goes the replacement of the 2 group} $3
```

I am struggling with the replacement :

```
Regex r = new Regex("^(\d{3})(.*)(\d{3})");
r.Replace(input,"$1 {Here goes the replacement of the 2 group} $3")
```

How should i write the replacement for the 2 group here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are correct, what is the problem you are facing ?

Comment: you write it as text: `$1helloworld$3`

Comment: in fact you dont need three match groups, you can simply use `$1` and `$2`

Comment: I need to determine the length of this string in the middle. Can i do it in the expression?

Comment: It is working and output is `123 {Here goes the replacement of the 2 group} 456`

Comment: @AlexArt. It is possible, will write an answer shortly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try the below regex which uses lookbehind and lookahead,

```
string str = "123456789123456";
string result = Regex.Replace(str, @"(?<=\d{3})\d(?=\d{3})", "x");
Console.WriteLine(result);
Console.ReadLine();
```

**Output:**

```
123xxxxxxxxx456
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/LOw7U4)

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/bA0jG5/5)

Comment: actually this is even better than what I've posted; I'm an idiot :)